# Limit of Lebesgue integrals

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification, lebesgue-integral

> Let $a>0$ and $f,g:[0,+\infty) \to \Bbb{R}$ where $f$ is a Lebesgue integrable function and $g$ has the property: $$|\frac{g(t)}{t}| \leq a, \forall t \geq 1$$.
>   Prove that $\lim_{t \to +\infty}\frac{1}{t}\int_1^tf(x)g(x)dx = 0$

Here is my proof:

$$|\frac{1}{t}\int_1^tf(x)g(x)dx| \leq \frac{1}{t}\int_1^t|f(x)||g(x)|dx$$ 
$$=\frac{1}{t}\int_1^{\sqrt{t}}|f(x)||g(x)|dx+\frac{1}{t}\int_{\sqrt{t}}^t|f(x)||g(x)|dx$$ $$\leq \frac{a||f||_1}{\sqrt{t}}+a\int_{\sqrt{t}}^t|f(x)|dx \to 0$$ as $t \to +\infty$ because $\int_{\sqrt{t}}^t|f(x)|dx \to 0$ from integrability of $f$.

Is this proof correct,or i am missing something?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is correct. But you can also get this as an immediate consequence of DCT: $\frac 1 t I_{(1,t)} f(t)g(t) \to 0$ for each $x$ and this function is dominated in absolute value by $a|f|$ which is integrable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer..Indeed,this is easier if we use DCT directly for $h_n(x)=\frac{f(x)g(x)}{t_n}1_{[1,t_n]}(x)$ for an arbitrary $t_n \to +\infty$